# Cannot install ubuntu 12.04 or 13.04 in dualboot with windows 8.1, UEFI

Tags: 12.04, 13.04

Hardware : asus g53sx laptop, nvidia 560m,sda SSD (Windows on it),sdb HDD  (subpartition with desired Ubuntu shrinked from it sdb5)

I tried to install 12.04. It works in Legacy Mode but after I install it i cannot boot it. (Secureboot unsupported, fastboot off). When I try to run the installer in UEFI, it freezes after the grub menu ("install ubuntu"). I tried all the noalpic, nomodeset etc, nothing seemed to work.

Then I installed 13.10 worked flawless, but found out in the end that i have to install either 12.04 or 13.04 (some packages that i need are only on those platforms) . So i tried 13.04

With 13.04, installer works fine in uefi, instalation goes flawless, but every time after, it loads just grub command line. so i run liveUSB, run RepairBoot, and after grub loads. If i select Ubuntu it will purple freeze. If i select "safe-mode" i get black screen! If i select windows boot loader it boots windows just fine.

RepairBoot file : http://paste.ubuntu.com/7069272

I read already checked a lot of simmiliar questions but none helped me whatsoever.

George

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since sdb is a MBR(msdos) partitioned drive it will only boot in BIOS mode. You would need to convert  it to gpt partitioning to boot with UEFI.

It also looks like you did the Boot-Repair 'buggy' UEFI rename. If booting Ubuntu in BIOS mode you do not need that. And best not to use that if your system will boot ubuntu if in UEFI mode. Only required for those systems/vendor that modify UEFI to only boot Windows. Boot-Repair cannot tell and just offer it if you run it more than once.

To undo & to rename files to their original names, you just need to tick the "Restore EFI backups" option of Boot-Repair.

UEFI and BIOS are not compatible. So once you start to boot in one mode you cannot change or use grub to select system. Or you can only boot from UEFI or perhaps one-time boot key if your system auto switches to match install mode. Some require you to turn on/off UEFI or CSM/BIOS boot mode to change in UEFI menu also.

I would suggest backing up data on sdb & convert to gpt partitioning since sda is UEFI with gpt partitioning.

GPT Advantages (older but still valid)  see post#2 by srs5694:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1457901

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GUID_Partition_Table#Advantages_of_GPT

You may be able to convert, but need good backups anyway.

http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html

Comment: Ok so i transformed to gpt, then ran livecd again, ran Bootrepair with restore efi backups and now it just insta-boots windows. What should i do?

Comment: Post link to newest BootInfo report. Did you create efi partition on second drive so you can directly boot that drive without Windows drive or did Boot-Repair or you new Ubuntu install put its boot files in the Windows drive's efi partition.